# problems in VSSadmin from c#

Tags: c#

I am executing the following code and it gives me the following error.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            p.StartInfo.FileName = "vssadmin";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "shadowstorage /for=C: /on=C: /maxsize=18%";
            p.Start();

            string error_presturacion = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();

            if (p.ExitCode == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + p);
            }
        }
    }
```

> The system cannot find the specified file

[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DKhE.png)

Comment: you probably need to give it a path + .exe extension.

Comment: Could you try with vssadmin.exe ?

Comment: It doesn't work, I already tried with vassadmin.exe and with the full path 
`Environment.SystemDirectory+"\\vssadmin"`

Comment: @jdweng so i did and it doesn't work, start VS as admin.

Comment: Either you do not have permission to read file, It is already opened, or the path is wrong.  See if you can find the file using a windows explorer.  Then check the permissions.  Not all admin account are the same.  Even if you have admin you still may not be able to open the file.

Comment: If the file is there and it runs correctly, if I do it with CMD it works fine.